# How do config tools like Consul "push" config updates to clients?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, configuration-management, netflix-eureka, consul

There is an emerging trend of ripping global state *out* of traditional "static" config management tools like Chef/Puppet/Ansible, and instead storing configurations in some centralized/distributed tool, of which the main players *appear* to be:

- ZooKeeper (Apache)
- Consul (Hashicorp)
- Eureka (Netflix)

Each of these tools works differently, but the principle is the same:

- Store your env vars and other dynamic configurations (that is, stuff that is subject to change) in these tools as key/value pairs
- Connect to these tools/services via clients at startup and pull down your config KV pairs. This typically requires the client to supply a service name ("`MY_APP`"), and an environment ("`DEV`", "`PROD`", etc.).

There is an [excellent Consul Java client](https://github.com/OrbitzWorldwide/consul-client) which explains all of this beautifully and provides ample code examples.

My *understanding* of these tools is that they are built on top of **consensus algorithms** such as Zab, Paxos and Gossip that allow config updates to spread almost *virally*, with eventual consistency, throughout your nodes. So the idea there is that if you have a `myapp` app that has 20 nodes, say `myapp01` through `myapp20`, if you make a config change to one of them, that change will naturally "spread" throughout the 20 nodes over a period of seconds/minutes.

My problem is: how do these updates *actually* deploy to each node? In none of the client APIs (the one I linked to above, the ZooKeeper API, or the Eureka API) do I see some kind of callback functionality that can be set up and used to notify the client when the centralized service (e.g. the Consul cluster) wants to push and reload config updates.

So I ask: how is this supposed to work (dynamic config deployment and reload on clients)? I'm interested in *any* viable answer for any of those 3 tools, though Consul's API seems to be the most advanced IMHO.

Comment: You can just periodically send request to consul to get KV's.

Comment: Thanks @Suvitruf (+1) - but are you *sure* there's no other way? [Consul uses Gossip](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/gossip.html), and the whole point of Gossip is to [spread **epidemically**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol#Gossip_communication), sort of like a "Server Push" in HTTP parlance. So I would have expected the Consul API to allow clients to register callbacks that can be notified in real-time (**not** via polling) as soon as updates are pushed. Ideas?

Comment: Don't know, really. I'm using consul only for services, without KV. And from apps periodically send TTL request for healthcheck, and send request for getting service with ?passing parameter (and here I can get special parameters from tags array, for example).

Comment: Looks like [watches](https://consul.io/docs/agent/watches.html) may be the answer here, if any Consul Gurus can weigh-in...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cfg4j](http://www.cfg4j.org/) for that. It's a Java configuration library for distributed services. It supports Consul as one of the configuration sources.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice question. I can tell how Consul HTTP client works.

I also think initially that it works in the push mechanism but while I was recently exploring Consul, I found that all Consul clients poll server for changes they want to watch. Although it is a bit different polling mechanism, Consul supports blocking queries. These are HTTP requests with a max timeout of 10 mins. This query waits until there is some change on the watched key/folder and return with the latest index. If the index is changed, the client reloads the configuration. For more info : [Consul Blocking Query](https://www.consul.io/api/features/blocking.html)